# go language web framework design thread wise

Tags: multithreading, web, go

What is the threading design of GO net/http library?
I heard [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN_DpYBzKso) a few days ago and I was really curious about how GO developers implemented their web framework design, thread wise.
I know node.js uses 1 Computational thread reading events and a pool of I/O threads. ASP.NET uses a thread per call... how does GO handle the C10K problem?

Answer (score 2):

The net/http server uses one goroutine per connection as stated in the [documentation](http://godoc.org/net/http#Serve).